# finding the residue ? Tough question

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Find  the  residue   at each of the  isolated   singularities of the  following  function on $\mathbb{C}$?

$1) \frac{z}{z^2+3z +3}$

$ii)  \frac{1}{(z^3 +1)(z+1)^2}$

My attempt : for  $1)   z^2 +3z + 3=  z^2 + 2z+z + 3$ where  $z = \frac{-3 +\sqrt 3^2 -12}{2}$
I know  that here  $z$ is  a  simple  pole

For  II) $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^3 +1)(z+1)^2}$ here $z=-1$  is pole of order  $2 $

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Where are you getting stuck, exactly?

Comment: @RyanGoulden actually here im confused about the pole

Comment: Actually, I think $z=-1$ in your second problem might be a pole of order $3$. Do you know the formula for calculating residues?

Comment: @RyanGoulden,,,ya  i thinks  by cauchy integral formula

Answer (score 1):

For your second problem, $f(z)= \frac{1}{(z^3 +1)(z+1)^2}$, you have $z=-1$ as a pole of order 3, and then 2 simple poles (can you see what they are?).

To calculate your pole of order 3, use the residue formula. You'll have $$\frac{1}{(3-1)!} \frac{d^2}{dz^2} (z+1)^3 f(z)$$. Then after differentiating, take the limit as it approaches the pole, $-1$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: i thinks   here   $(z^3 +1) $  not $(z+1)^3$

Comment: It is supposed to be how I've written it. The formula calls for $(z-c)^n f(z)$, where $c$ is the location of the pole and $n$ is its order. $-1$ is a pole of order 3 since $(z+1)^2$ and $z^3 +1$ are both $0$ when $z=-1$. So ultimately, you'll differentiate twice the function $\frac{z+1}{z^3 +1}$. Does this make sense?